# Copy specific file from every subfolder with parent directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I need a way of looping through sub-directories in a large directory (/home/data/playerdata/) in order to get a specific file while keeping the parent folders name of that specific file I'm trying to get.

I basically need this in order to restore one specific file from a backup.

Example:

Main directory to be looped = `/home/minecraft/survival1/plugins/Survival/playerdata/`

Path of the specific file I'm trying to restore = `/home/minecraft/survival1/plugins/Survival/playerdata/004fc15d-294c-4a42-a1af-1206c148e39b/economy.yml`

Example command for script to exucute in a loop = `cp /home/minecraft/survival1/plugins/Survival/playerdata/004fc15d-294c-4a42-a1af-1206c148e39b/economy.yml /restored/playerdata/004fc15d-294c-4a42-a1af-1206c148e39b/economy.yml`

I need a script that will loop through each folder (The UUID bit) in the "playerdata" directory and copy that one specific file while retaining its UUID parent folder.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 for FILE in $BASEDIR
        cp $BASEDIR/FILE/economy.yml /home/restored/FILE/economy.yml
```

This is running on a Debian server

Comment: So basically you wan't to get this economy file from every folder in that directory `/home/minecraft/survival1/plugins/Survival/<player_uuid>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using find for this:

```sh
cd /home/minecraft/survival1/plugins/Survival/playerdata/
find -name "economy.yml" -exec cp --parents {} /home/minecraft/restore/ \;
```

`--parents` saves the directory structure while making copies.

Or using a for cycle, like you tried:

```sh
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename;
do 
  mkdir --parents "$RESTOREDIR/$player"
  cp "$BASEDIR/$player/economy.yml" "$RESTOREDIR/$player/economy.yml"
done
```